# PyQt5 Treeview unwanted expanding of index, when using QSortFilterProxyModel on a subclassed QtCore.QAbstractItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

My issue happens when I expand any item in my treeview(besides the top item), and pick its child. Then the top item **also** expands to show its children.

Example:
I have 2 children under root, each with its own child:

```
root
|-A  
  |-child AA
| 
|-B
  |-child BB
```

**The issue:** When I expand B and pick child BB in my treeview, it also opens(expands) A for some reason.
If we add another item under root, C with a child CC, and expand that instead of B; A will still expand as soon as child CC is picked.

I'm using a custom class as base items and I'm using my own class of QAbstractItemModel as sourceModel for the QSortFilterProxyModel. I'm sure the problem lies somewhere in those two custom classes but I can't figure why it happens.

I have a working example further down. It includes a few bits and pieces of the original script, so it might seem a bit messy.

The top treeview is using the proxy(and having the issue) and the one below is skipping the proxy and is not having any issue.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.custom_nodes = [] #A list that will contain all our custom nodes.
        #list of stand-in dicts:
        self.all_node_list = [{'node_name': 'A', 'parent': None, 'children': [{'node_name': 'AB', 'parent': 'A','children': [{'node_name': 'ABC','parent': 'AB','children': []}]}]},
                              {'node_name': 'Prop', 'parent': None, 'children': [{'node_name': 'SubProp', 'parent': 'Prop','children': [{'node_name': 'Asset', 'parent': 'SubProp', 'children': []}]}]}]
        self.MakeNodesFromDict(self.all_node_list,None)#Make custom nodes from dict
        self.tree_model = CustomModel(self.custom_nodes) #Create custom model
        self.CreateWindow()

    def CreateWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Top proxy - below normal")
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        #SEARCH BAR
        self.menu_search_bar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.menu_search_bar)

        #TREE VIEW USING PROXY MODEL
        self.proxy_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.proxy_tree.setObjectName("treeView")
        self.proxy_tree.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.proxy_tree.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.proxy_tree.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(True)
        self.proxy_tree.setAnimated(True)
        self.proxy_tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.proxy_tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.proxy_tree.setObjectName("proxy_treeView")
        self.proxy_tree.setWindowTitle("Dir View")

        #THE PROXY MODEL
        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self.proxy_tree)
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.tree_model)
        self.proxyModel.setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(True)
        self.proxyModel.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxy_tree.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.proxyModel.sort(0, 0)

        #Connect proxy bar to tree
        self.menu_search_bar.textChanged.connect(self.ProxyUpdate)
        self.menu_search_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.SearchEnter)

        #TREE VIEW WITHOUT PROXY MODEL
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.tree.setObjectName("treeView")
        self.tree.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.tree.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.tree.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(True)
        self.tree.setAnimated(True)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tree.setModel(self.tree_model)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.proxy_tree)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    ###########################################################
    #################### FUNCTIONS ############################
    ###########################################################
    def MakeNodesFromDict(self,cur_list, cur_parent):
        for t in cur_list:
            cur_node = CustomNode(node_name=t["node_name"], children=[],_parent=cur_parent)
            if cur_parent:
                cur_parent.addChild(cur_node)
            self.MakeNodesFromDict(t["children"], cur_node)
            self.custom_nodes.append(cur_node)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str) # <--Not sure if this is needed?
    def ProxyUpdate(self,text):
        my_pattern = QtCore.QRegularExpression()
        my_pattern.setPatternOptions(QtCore.QRegularExpression.CaseInsensitiveOption)
        my_pattern.setPattern(text)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegularExpression(my_pattern)

    def SearchEnter(self): #opens or closes the tree view after search
        if self.menu_search_bar.text() == "":
            self.proxy_tree.collapseAll()
        else:
            self.proxy_tree.expandAll()


class CustomModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel): #Custom model to work with custom nodes
    def __init__(self, nodes): #Give all custom nodes at init
        QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)
        self._root = CustomNode() #Create root object of custom model as a custom node aswell
        self.nodes = nodes
        for node in self.nodes:
            if node.parent()==None: #Go through and add nodes with no parents (top nodes)
                self._root.addChild(node)

    def emitDataChanged(self):
        self.dataChanged.emit(QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QModelIndex())

    def rowCount(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            node = index.internalPointer()
            return node.childCount()
        return self._root.childCount()

    def addChild(self, node, _parent):
        if not _parent or not _parent.isValid():
            parent = self._root
        else:
            parent = _parent.internalPointer()
        parent.addChild(node)

    def index(self, row, column, _parent=None):
        if not _parent or not _parent.isValid():
            node_parent = self._root
        else:
            node_parent = _parent.internalPointer()

        if not QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.hasIndex(self, row, column, _parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        child = node_parent.child(row)
        if child:
            return QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(self, row, column, child)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            p = index.internalPointer().parent()
            if p:
                return QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(self, p.row(), 0, p)
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def columnCount(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return index.internalPointer().columnCount()
        return self._root.columnCount()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        node = index.internalPointer()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return node.data(index.column())
        return None

    def getNode(self, index):
        return index.internalPointer()

    def update(self, index):
        pass

class CustomNode(object):
    def __init__(self, column_count=1,row=0,children=[],node_name="root",_parent=None):
        self._column_count = column_count
        self._row = row
        self.node_name = node_name
        self._parent = _parent
        self._children = children

    def addChild(self, child):
        child._parent = self
        child._row = self.childCount()
        self._children.append(child)
        self._column_count = max(child.columnCount(), self._column_count)

    def GetName(self):
        return self.node_name

    def GetChildren(self):
        return self._children

    def data(self, column):
        return self.node_name

    def columnCount(self):
        return self._column_count

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def child(self, row):
        if row >= 0 and row < self.childCount():
            return self._children[row]

    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    def row(self):
        return self._row


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I had some trouble with working out how to subclass QAbstractItemModel and use your own object class as elements. So what you see here is half trial and error and half stackoverflow answers, all put together :)

Comment: I don't understand your problem, explain yourself better. Point out an example that you get now and would like to get.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry I'll try to be more clear in my question. I'll update my post with a new explanation.